# Access refs of sub component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, refs

If I have a component like:

```
class Sliders extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Slider ref="first" update={this.props.update} />
        <Slider ref="second" update={this.props.update} />
        <Slider ref="third" update={this.props.update} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

and I want to set up another component that accesses the value using it's ref, is there a way to do this?

```
class App extends React.Component {
    sliderUpdate(){
         console.log(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.third).value)
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Sliders update={this.sliderUpdate} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

this doesn't work because it seems like the refs don't carry over to the App class.

Comment: declare a function that returns the value of refs.. then pass a prop to access the function that returns it

Comment: do you have an example I could look at?  This is tough for me to grasp

Comment: so you're saying my updateFunction would take the current ref as an argument?

Comment: sorry for i don't have an example available.. the idea is just like you're passing a props (which is a function) to the child component. and that child component will call the props for a certain event. which will eventually received by the parent component

Comment: check this fiddle i do for you [fidle](https://jsfiddle.net/marloeleven/w1am0s9z/1/)

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved without using `refs`.

Sample code would be as below,

```
const handleChange = (val) => (
    console.log(val)
)
const Application = () => (
    <div>
    <Slider handleChange={handleChange} />
    </div>
);

const Slider = (props) => (
  <div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="typesomething" onChange={(e) => props.handleChange(e.target.value)}></input>
  </div>
)
```

Check this [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LkKdpq?editors=0010)